# Install mongodb-3.6 amazon ec2 Ubuntu issue

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I follow this tutorial: [enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
To install mongodb on Ubuntu 16.04 amazon ec2.

But when i check if the service is ok, i found this:

[image]

Why? How to solve?

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement* are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)". Also, please (re)read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask  before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Are you serious? Please, i put the steps that I followed in the link.

If you do not want to help, do nothing.

Comment: You need to create the `/data/db` directory. (the command is `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create this (`/data/db`) directory as root

Either you need to use `sudo` , e.g. `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`

Or you need to do `su -` to become superuser, and then create the directory with `mkdir -p /data/db`

**Note:**

MongoDB also has an option where you can create the data directory in another location, but that's generally not a good idea, because it just slightly complicates things such as DB recovery, because you always have to specify the db-path manually.

Answer (score 1):

create **data/db** directory in root and give read and write permission

```
cd /
sudo mkdir data
sudo mkdir data/db
sudo chown -R $USER /data/db
sudo chown -R $USER /tmp/
```